# How can I directly store value into memory?

Tags: android, assembly, arm

So, I'm doing reverse engineer to a vendor blob, which is ARMV8 Little Endian Thumb, so far I know, you can't add any instruction, so the problem comes here.

I'm looking to a way to directly store an unsigned integer value to the memory (address offset), I can't use this way.

```
MOV R1, 0x0
STR R1, [Memory Address]
```

Because if I replace previous instruction, the vendor blob may broke, and for me, it's a little dirty.

I'm still beginning at this, but is there any instruction like STR but allowing us to store value into memory?, If you haven't understand yet, something like this.

```
STR 0x0, [Memory Address]
```

Apologies of the lack of description beforehand!

Comment: All store instructions in AArch32 mode require you to load the datum to be stored into a register first.  There are no store immediate or memory-to-memory move instructions.

Comment: You may be able to look back in the code and deduce that some other register already contains zero.  Otherwise maybe you can write your sequence of instructions elsewhere in memory, and patch in a branch.

Comment: when you look at the arm documentation you see that this does not exist

Comment: You definitely can't.

Comment: In AArch64 there's an always-zero register which you could store, but 32-bit mode doesn't work that way.  You may be able to code-golf / optimize for size in a block to free up space to zero a register, and find one you can safely zero at that point...